# How to get jQuery alert on ios?

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, iphone

The alert from `<span class="close">&times;</span>` works fine on all browsers on a computer, however does not work on a mobile device ...
When i try to run the page on the iPhone, the `<span class="close">&times;</span>` does not give any alert.

How can I fix this?

```js
  var closebtns = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < closebtns.length; i++) {
    closebtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
   alert("X was clicked");
    });
  }
```

```css
      body {font-family: sans-serif;}

 input { font-size: 1em; } /* prevent zoom in mobile */

 ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
 }

 ul li {
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
   background-color: #f6f6f6;
   padding: 12px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 18px;
   color: black;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   min-height: 1em;
   z-index: 999;
   max-width: 360px;
 }

 ul li:hover {
   background-color: #eee;
 }
  

 /* sortable plugin styles when dragged */
 .dragged {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2000;
 }

 li.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  background: purple; 
 }

 .close {
   cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   right: 0%;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   transform: translate(0%, -50%);
   z-index: 99999;
 }

 .close:hover {background: #bbb;}
```

```html
<div id="sort-it">
    <ul>
      <li>This is item #1<span class="close">&times;</span></li>       
      <li>This is item #2<span class="close">&times;</span></li>        
      <li>This is item #3<span class="close">&times;</span></li>        
      <li>This is item #4<span class="close">&times;</span></li>      
      <li>This is item #5<span class="close">&times;</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hereby the solution to make the click on the button mobile friendly .
The solution is to define touchstart in the click event.

```
$('.close').on('click touchstart', function(e)
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.close').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).closest('li').attr('id'));
   }); 
});
```

```css
  body {font-family: sans-serif;}

 input { font-size: 1em; } /* prevent zoom in mobile */

 ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
 }

 ul li {
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
   background-color: #f6f6f6;
   padding: 12px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 18px;
   color: black;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   min-height: 1em;
   max-width: 360px;
 }

 ul li:hover {
   background-color: #eee;
 }
  

 /* sortable plugin styles when dragged */
 .dragged {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2000;
 }

 li.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  background: purple; 
 }

 .close {
   cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   right: 0%;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   transform: translate(0%, -50%);
   background: #fff;
 }

 .close:hover {background: #bbb;}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sort-it">
    <ul>
      <li id="ID_1">This is item #1<button class="close">&times;</button></li>       
      <li id="ID_2">This is item #2<button class="close">&times;</button></li>        
      <li id="ID_3">This is item #3<button class="close">&times;</button></li>        
      <li id="ID_4">This is item #4<button class="close">&times;</button></li>      
      <li id="ID_5">This is item #5<button class="close">&times;</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```